# pandas version upgrade 0.24.2 apply problem

Tags: python, pandas

Upgraded my pandas version to 0.24.2 and having problems with running existing code:

*base_smile* is a dataframe,

*xbar* is a float,

*spot* is also a float

I am just trying a simple apply that used to work just fine in the older version.

```
base_smile['xbar'] = base_smile.apply(lambda row: xbar if row['strike'] > spot else (-1)*xbar, axis=1)
```

For the new version, I had to tweak it like this using .any().

```
base_smile['xbar'] = base_smile.apply(lambda row: xbar if row['strike'].any() > spot else (-1)*xbar, axis=1)
```

Can someone explain why and  if there is a better way. I don't like the .any().

Answer (score 0):

Your new code probably doesn't do what you want.  Anyway it can be rewritten in a better way:

```
base_smile['xbar'] *= np.where(base_smile['strike'] > spot, 1, -1)
```

This will work in any version, and be much faster.